# How can I add test cases running in loop to Junit report generated through SOAPUI

Tags: junit, soapui

I am running test cases in Data driven manner. 
Have created on TestSuite with single Testcases and multiple request.The test cases are fetched through external source (xls) and are executed via single testcase/Request using loop.

Now in the generated Junit report, am getting test cases count as 1 and Single test case name.

How can i add all the testcases running in loop to Junit report?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the test is data driven, then it is single test case only.

Let us assume, if the test is failed for one of row of the data, you can't run the test for that specific row, the test needs to be run for entire data again.

So, what you get is correct. You need not to quantify the number of test cases for each row of the data.